# Confused by property :ID: versus :CUSTOM_ID:

Tags: org-mode

I use org-id to automatically create ID.

For instance in an org mode file:
*File_A.org*

```
* File_A section
```

I type `C-c l` that create an id

```
* File_A section
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       21588817-03d2-4000-8d37-43649499eff6
  :END:
```

Then I want to include *File_A section* in another file, *File_B.org*,

*(in File_B.org)*

```
#+INCLUDE: "file_A.org::#21588817-03d2-4000-8d37-43649499eff6"
```

However, this does **not** work (`C-c '` does not follow the link).

To make it works I have to manually add a redundant "CUSTOM_ID" property.

```
* File_A section
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       21588817-03d2-4000-8d37-43649499eff6
  :CUSTOM_ID: 21588817-03d2-4000-8d37-43649499eff6
  :END:
```

I am confused by the role of `:ID:` and `:CUSTOM_ID:`...

Why on one side Org-Mode's `#+INCLUDE:`s follow `:CUSTOM_ID:` ([official doc](https://orgmode.org/manual/Search-options.html#Search-options)) and on the other side, org-id's links (`C-c l` and `C-c C-l`) use `:ID:` ([official org-mode/org-id.el file](https://github.com/tkf/org-mode/blob/master/lisp/org-id.el))?

Ideally I do not want to have a **redundant** and **manually** added:CUSTOM_ID: every time I use `#+INCLUDE:`.
My question: is there a **clean** way to `#+INCLUDE:` a section using `:ID:` and not `:CUSTOM_ID:`?

---

Update: on Apr 29 2022 the problem is still present (org mode version 9.5.2)

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me (probably on the include side).

Comment: This link [Org Navigation Revisited - The Chronicle](https://blog.aaronbieber.com/2016/07/31/org-navigation-revisited.html) may be of some help

Answer (score 11):

Forget about ID, used to generate unique identifiers (likely to be used by downstream libraries, not users), and use CUSTOM_ID.

To insert it, forget about `C-c l` and use `C-c C-x p` to set a property. You can then select CUSTOM_ID. You can also include a heading directly by it's name:

```
#+INCLUDE: file.org::*File_A section
```

When giving your headings CUSTOM_IDs, prefer names that make sense for you, so that you can make sense of the heading in the includer file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your point, however I like :ID: because I think that they are more robust (org-id keeps a ID database). For instance if I rename *File_A.org* to *something_else.org* my links will always work (Emacs scan the agenda files). This is not the case if my links explicitly use the file name (CUSTOM_ID case).

Comment: If the heading subtree is archived, links to its `CUSTOM_ID` will fail. If you change the heading by editing to something else, the `#+INCLUDE: file.org::*File_A section` will fail too.

Comment: How would one jump to the custom id?  `M-x search-forward CUSTOM_ID: value` (or backward) is cumbersome...